# trying to create the Logseq desktop GUI using docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

When i'm trying to do Logseq Desktop GUI launch docker-compose up i'm facing below issue

WARNING: Image for service logseq was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating logseq_logseq_1 ... done
Attaching to logseq_logseq_1
logseq_1  | sh: 1: /opt/logseq/Logseq: not found

after doing docker-compose build it's showing container Re-starting position. kindly help me to resolve the issue

Kindly provide the dockerfile and docker-compose up code.